# Filter array of dictionaries - SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have the following array:

```
[[user1ID: NSDate], [user2ID: NSDate], [user3ID: NSDate]]
```

Can it be filtered out so I only get the dictionary with `user2ID`?

Comment: As a sidenote: can your array also contain multiple-key dictionaries? Like `[[user1ID: NSDate], [user2ID: NSDate, user3ID: NSDate], [user3ID: NSDate]]`? If not, you might want to consider using a simple dictionary like so: `[user1ID: NSDate, user2ID: NSDate, user3ID: NSDate]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let test = [["user1ID": NSDate()], ["user2ID": NSDate()], ["user3ID": NSDate()]]
let newArray = test.filter { $0.keys.contains("user2ID") }.flatMap { $0 }

print(newArray) // ["user2ID": 2016-01-28 10:52:29 +0000]
```

I've edited your dictionary a bit for testing purposes.

Answer to your comment:

If you simply want to know if the array contains a dictionary with "user2ID" as key you can do the following:

```
test.contains { $0.keys.contains("user2ID") } ? print("yep!") : print("nope!") // "Yep!"
```

Comment: Dear @Eendje, maybe you know the answer to this also: how can I check that the array has in it dictionary with user2ID?

Comment: Updated the answer ;)

Comment: I know! :p Anything else I can help with?

Comment: I have lots of pizza's here.. :p

Comment: And now I'm also fat. No one came here to pick up a pizza.. :(